# Emails sent using smtpmail / mu4e appear in Gmail Inbox

Tags: mu4e, smtpmail

Emails sent using smtpmail / mu4e appear in Gmail Inbox, both when checked in mu4e and Gmail interface.

I have the following in my .init.el:

```
(setq
 mu4e-maildir       "~/.mail"   ;; top-level Maildir
 mu4e-drafts-folder "/gmail/[Gmail]/Drafts"
 mu4e-sent-folder   "/gmail/[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
 mu4e-trash-folder  "/gmail/[Gmail]/Trash"
 mu4e-refile-folder "/gmail/[Gmail]/All Mail"
 mu4e-user-mail-address-list '("[email]"))

(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
     smtpmail-stream-type 'tls
     smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
     smtpmail-auth-credentials (expand-file-name "~/.authinfo.gpg")
     smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
     smtpmail-smtp-service 465)

(setq mu4e-sent-messages-behavior 'delete)
```

My .mbsync has the following contents:

```
IMAPAccount gmail
# Address to connect to
Host imap.gmail.com
User [email]
SSLVersions TLSv1.1
# Pass ***************
# To store the password in an encrypted file use PassCmd instead of Pass
PassCmd "gpg2 -q --for-your-eyes-only --no-tty -d ~/.mailpass.gpg"
#
# Use SSL
SSLType IMAPS
# The following line should work. If get certificate errors, uncomment the two following lines and read the "Troubleshooting" section.
CertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
#CertificateFile ~/.cert/imap.gmail.com.pem
#CertificateFile ~/.cert/Equifax_Secure_CA.pem

IMAPStore gmail-remote
Account gmail

MaildirStore gmail-local
Subfolders Verbatim
# The trailing "/" is important
Path ~/.mail/gmail/
Inbox ~/.mail/gmail/Inbox

Channel gmail
Master :gmail-remote:
Slave :gmail-local:
Patterns * ![Gmail]* "[Gmail]/Sent" "[Gmail]/Drafts" "[Gmail]/Trash" "[Gmail]/Starred" "[Gmail]/All Mail"
Create Both
SyncState *
Sync All
```

My .mail dir has the following structure:

[image: .email tree]

Comment: I voted to close as the problem appears to have been caused by a misconfigured gmail account, and didn't have anything to do with Emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had the email address I was using as a test recipient set up as an extra  "Send email as" account in Gmail.